# Why executing ('Hello','world!) returns 'world!'?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning programming with JavaScript, and I just don't know what's happening here:

```
let myVar = ('Hello','World!');
console.log(myVar);
```

The output is:

```
World!
```

Comment: If you meant for it to be an array, you need to use square brackets `[]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

This means that the expression `'Hello','World!'` evaluates to `'World!'`

Comment: One more thing to note: JavaScript doesn't use parentheses to as the literal syntax for any type of collection, so putting parentheses around that just ensures that it will be grouped as a single expression.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the variable to the string "Hello", then setting it to "World". The same thing happens if you set a list of variables inside a parenthetical.

```
const myVar = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
console.log(myVar);
//6
```

Where as I think what you were trying to do was use a grouping operator like `+`.

```
const myVar = ("Hello, " + "World")
console.log(myVar)
//"Hello, World"
```